# bash - print env vars in the order they were set

Tags: linux, bash

This question pertains to the bash shell

First off, I know how to look at the env vars that are currently set.

I want to know how to list the currently set environment variables in the order they were set. Kind of like "ls -lt" but for env vars.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** many were asking why I need this.

I do a lot of debugging, code porting, fixing etc. It requires me to experiment with third party codes that are not always well written. During the process of getting to a successful build, I might need to set, overwrite some env vars. I am pretty good at documenting what I am doing so I can retrace my steps. But sometimes I forget or miss to record my steps.

For very good reasons, our env has a ton of env vars.

I can capture the entire env vars at that moment, but that doesnt help me much. If bash had a way to list env vars in the order they were set, I can clearly identify what I had set.

Also, I agree that there is no reason for bash to track this. But I was hoping it has an internal stack of env vars, which automatically is ordered as last-in-first-out. But I guess that was just too optimistic to expect.

thanks to everyone.

Comment: I don't believe it is.  No.

Comment: Do you have a specific set of environment variables in mind, or do you want to do this for the entire environment?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible.

Comment: I can't think of any particular reason for bash to track that information.

Comment: **Why** do you want this? Sounds like an X-Y problem.

Comment: What do you need this for? If it's just for your personal bash use, you could alias `export` to include such functionality: `function trackenv_export() { export "$@" && echo "$*" >> "$HOME"/.env_track; }; alias export=trackenv_export` . But that's quite messy and probably not what you're after.

Comment: @pmos, this sounds promising. I will try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @pmos suggested in a comment, you might be able to hack some shell function that would manually track when you export something, but the shell itself cannot do this. Here's why. Export makes a name available to the environment. That is only meaningful to the `exec*e` family of functions. In other words, `export` is really only meaningful to new processes following the standard `fork/exec` pattern. But this also means the data structure holding the exported names is not up to the shell, but POSIX C. Here's a fragment of [documentation about exec environments](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html):

> The argument envp is an array of character pointers to null-terminated strings. These strings shall constitute the environment for the new process image. The envp array is terminated by a null pointer.

and

> `extern char **environ;` is initialized as a pointer to an array of character pointers to the environment strings.

It might seem reasonable to assume that processes add strings to the environment in order, but it doesn't really seem to work that way in fact, and POSIX systems being as complex as they are, it's not surprising they do a lot of setting, resetting and unsetting.

Despite your question focusing on *environment* variables, your phrasing makes me think you're also interested in tracking when variables get `set`, which is different from when they get `export`ed. That actually *is* entirely the shell's problem, but alas, bash (at least) seems not to track this either.

`set` seems to display the names in alphabetical order. I can't even figure out what ordering the external `env` command displays them in.

Comment: `env(1)` [uses](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/ece7157933fea925da10b5c3e7ace1f0fb2d9f50/src/env.c#L164-L171) the ordering of [`environ(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) itself. [`setenv(3)`](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/setenv.c;h=3e68149ddfb9b5b30b5642fdd6c544d741ba1e9f;hb=f1d237df1eec1df8cbc34f95540fd4035776e79c) is likely to be responsible for "disordering" (although I don't see any search for free slots in its code).